# How to fix socket manager error in chrome driver ver 116

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Please have me to fix this err
I use chromediver ver 116.0.5845.9600
Err:
[13020:16620:0831/160006.941:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
I try to handle this problem by add more chrome options but it cound not fix